# Pyramid Traversal: Changing __getitem__ behavior if a resource isn't the last in the chain

Tags: python, join, pyramid, traversal

I have a question regarding URL traversal in the Pyramid python web framework.

Imagine the following endpoints for a forum:

```
/forum/1 - Returns information about Forum #1
/forum/1/threads/1 - Returns Thread #1 in Forum #1
```

Here's how the traversal would work for the first URL:

1. A `Root` resource is created
2. `Root.__getitem__("forum")` is called. This returns a `ForumDispatch` resource.
3. `ForumDispatch.__getitem__("1")` is called. The database is queried for a Forum with ID 1. If it is not found, a `KeyError` is raised. If it is found, a `Forum` object is returned, and view lookup begins with `Forum` as a context.

Here's how the traversal would work for the second URL

1. A `Root` resource is created
2. `Root.__getitem__("forum")` is called. This returns a `ForumDispatch` resource.
3. `ForumDispatch.__getitem__("1")` is called. The database is queried for a `Forum` with ID 1. If it is not found, a `KeyError` is raised. If it is found, a `Forum` object is returned.
4. `Forum.__getitem__("threads")` is called. A `ThreadsDispatch` object is returned
5. `ThreadsDispatch.__getitem__("1")` is called. The database is queried for a `Thread` #1 in `Forum` #1. If it is found, a `Thread` object is returned and view lookup begins, or a `KeyError` is raised.

Now, for the first URL, a single query is issued. It would look like `SELECT ... FROM forums WHERE forums.id = 1;`. In the second URL, two queries are issued. `SELECT ... FROM forums WHERE forums.id = 1;`, and `SELECT ... FROM threads WHERE thread.id = 1 AND forum.id = 1;`.

I don't want two queries to be issued. For the second URL, the query `SELECT ... FROM forums LEFT JOIN threads ON threads.forum_id = forums.id WHERE threads.id = 1 AND forums.id = 1;` would return all the information needed. Then, I could return a KeyError if no rows are returned, or if a `Forum` is returned but not a `Thread`.

In order to accomplish this, the `ForumDispatch.__getitem__` needs to behave differently (e.g. change the query, or don't query at all) if it knows that "threads" is also going to be called next.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

I could, instead of returning actual database objects, create "dummy" resources to be returned by `ForumDispatch.__getitem__` and the like, and then have the view perform the necessary query. But, I feel like I'm losing out on some of the traversal functionality by making the view worry about querying/raising 404 errors. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a book-case example of premature optimization :)

Fetching a single row from a database via its primary key is the fastest possible operation your database can do. I would expect it to take about 1 millisecond or less.

A query with a join is somewhat more complex, involves accessing two tables and an index and performing the actual join. Most surely it'll take a bit longer - let's say, it'll be just 50% slower than a single row fetch, about 1.5 ms. Depending on the number of rows, it may actually take more than that, because joins are not totally free.

So, the total time to make two simple queries would be ~2ms versus ~1.5ms for a join query. So you're looking at ~0.5 ms difference at best. Or none. Or maybe a bit of a slow-down, you never know. Anyway, if you put it in the context of a web-application, any savings will be totally negligible compared to the network latency, HTTP round-trips, browser page reflows etc. You would get much more bang for your buck spending time optimizing the areas where you can achieve some measurable benefit :)

Surely, when you're finding that your page is making tens or hundreds of queries (often when displaying a listing) it's time to spend time configuring eager-loading in SQLAlchemy. Replacing two simple queries with one more complex query is only going to complicate things without bringing any measurable benefits.